# Unable to append div and change display mode

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one div with id `controlContainer` and I have 3 other `div` whose `display` is `none` and I am appending and prepending them using jQuery, and changing the `display` mode to `block` but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  if (i = 1) {
    var group = $('#beforeUpload').clone().attr("id", "beforeUpload" + i);
    $(group).css("Display", "block");
    $(group).appendTo("#controlContainer");

    var group2 = $("#uploadHeading").clone().attr("id", "uploadHeading" + i);
    $(group).css("Display", "block");
    $("#beforeUpload" + i).prepend(group2);

    var group5 = $('#afterUpload').clone().attr("id", "afterUpload" + i);
    $(group).css("Display", "block");
    $(group5).appendTo("#beforeUpload" + i);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="controlContainer">
  <h1>Main Container</h1>
</div>
<div id="beforeUpload" style="display: none;">
  <h2>It will append to "Main Container" and this is Before Upload</h2>
</div>
<div id="uploadHeading" style="display: none;">
  <h4>It will prepend to "Main Container" and this is Upload Heading</h4>
</div>
<div id="afterUpload" style="display: none;">
  <h3>It will append to "Main Container" and this is After Upload</h3>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All the issues are caused by typos. Firstly `Display` needs to be `display`. Secondly you've reused `group` in several places instead of the correct `groupN` variable. Also note that your `if` statement is redundant, and jQuery 1.7.1 is very outdated and requires updating

Comment: NOTE `if (i = 1)` is wrong: it assigns the value `1` to `i` and then treats the assignment outcome as a boolean. It should be either `if (i == 1)` or, even more accurate, `if (i === 1)`.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan your suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan stated:

1.`Display` needs to be `display`.

2.You've reused `group` variable in several places instead of the correct `groupN` variable.

3.`if (i = 1) { //assignment` needs to be `if (i == 1) { //comparison`

Correct that and your code will work.

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var i = 1;
  if (i == 1) { //check with ==
    var group = $('#beforeUpload').clone().attr("id", "beforeUpload" + i);
    $(group).css("display", "block");
    $(group).appendTo("#controlContainer");
    
    var group2 = $("#uploadHeading").clone().attr("id", "uploadHeading" + i);
    $(group2).css("display", "block"); // need to be group2 instead of group
    $("#beforeUpload" + i).prepend(group2);
    
    var group5 = $('#afterUpload').clone().attr("id", "afterUpload" + i);
    $(group5).css("display", "block");// need to be group5 instead of group
    $(group5).appendTo("#beforeUpload" + i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="controlContainer">
      <h1>Main Container</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div id="beforeUpload" style="display: none;">
      <h2>It will append to "Main Container" and this is Before Upload</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div id="uploadHeading" style="display: none;">
      <h4>It will prepend to "Main Container" and this is Upload Heading</h4>
    </div>
    
    <div id="afterUpload" style="display: none;">
      <h3>It will append to "Main Container" and this is After Upload</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note:- Try to use latest jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your Display should be display in css wasn't correct secondly you were not appending to right group and i have also updated latest jquery version.

This will work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    if (i = 1) {
        var group = $('#beforeUpload').clone().attr("id", "beforeUpload" + i);
        $(group).css("display", "block");
        $(group).appendTo("#controlContainer");

        var group2 = $("#uploadHeading").clone().attr("id", "uploadHeading" + i);
        $(group2).css("display", "block");
        $("#beforeUpload" + i).prepend(group2);

        var group5 = $('#afterUpload').clone().attr("id", "afterUpload" + i);
        $(group5).css("display", "block");
        $(group5).appendTo("#beforeUpload" + i);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="controlContainer">
  <h1>Main Container</h1>
 </div>


 <div id="beforeUpload" style="display: none;">
  <h2>It will append to "Main Container" and this is Before Upload</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="uploadHeading" style="display: none;">
  <h4>It will prepend to "Main Container" and this is Upload Heading</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="afterUpload" style="display: none;">
  <h3>It will append to "Main Container" and this is After Upload</h3>
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="UploadCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Got it .. I wrote down